# Restoring after a reinstall centOS

Tags: centos, restore

Basically my OVH server was reformatted without my permission using the manager panel. I'm using Centos 6.

How would I go about recovering those files? Specifically - I need to recover my user database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The hard drive was reformatted and CentOS reinstalled?  Unfortunately, if you don't have backups of the data, recovery is highly unlikely.

Have you contacted OVH to see if they have any recovery options?